# android ad full screen pop up layout

Tags: android, layout, admob

Sorry but I only know about ad banner.

I have seen some other apps that once the app is started, it would show a full screen ad popup (just like a dialog box and with a X at top right corner).

How could that be made? Would there be any examples?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad mob calls the type of ad that you are after an interstitial ad. They have a fully build in ad with an `x` in the top corner so the user can close it. There is a tutorial for is here (you have to select the android tab) -

- https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#android